# Python - Rebuilding a table from a Wikipedia page

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, data-analysis

I am new at learning Python and am attempting to rebuild a table found on a page in Wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Pixar_films). I was following a YouTube video to accomplish my goal, but I am stuck.

My current table has a double-height row for the header in one of the sections (Writers: Story, Screenplay). From looking at the table, I am wanting to remove the Writers cell, and only see the Story and Screenplay cells.

I am also looking to remove the last 2 header cells (Elio, Inside Out 2) as they aren't relevant to the table I am attempting to rebuild.

Any help or guidance?

In the end, I get this error as I know the number of columns does not equal the rows generated.

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[16], line 6
      3 individual_row_data = [data.text.strip() for data in row_data]
      5 length = len(df)
----> 6 df.loc[length] = individual_row_data

File ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py:818, in _LocationIndexer.__setitem__(self, key, value)
    815 self._has_valid_setitem_indexer(key)
    817 iloc = self if self.name == "iloc" else self.obj.iloc
--> 818 iloc._setitem_with_indexer(indexer, value, self.name)

File ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py:1785, in _iLocIndexer._setitem_with_indexer(self, indexer, value, name)
   1782     indexer, missing = convert_missing_indexer(indexer)
   1784     if missing:
-> 1785         self._setitem_with_indexer_missing(indexer, value)
   1786         return
   1788 if name == "loc":
   1789     # must come after setting of missing

File ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py:2160, in _iLocIndexer._setitem_with_indexer_missing(self, indexer, value)
   2157     if is_list_like_indexer(value):
   2158         # must have conforming columns
   2159         if len(value) != len(self.obj.columns):
-> 2160             raise ValueError("cannot set a row with mismatched columns")
   2162     value = Series(value, index=self.obj.columns, name=indexer)
   2164 if not len(self.obj):
   2165     # We will ignore the existing dtypes instead of using
   2166     #  internals.concat logic

ValueError: cannot set a row with mismatched columns
```

I can share the file if that is easiest. Thank you for the assistance.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask]. We do not write answers here that "find the bug"; we require a **specific** question - which will come out of your best attempt to [understand](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/) and [locate](//ericlippert.com/2014/03/05) a specific problem, and showcase it in a [mre]. A question that is suitable for Stack Overflow is one where you have already figured out the **specific part** of the code that does something different from what you expect (and you should concretely *expect something*), and don't understand why.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly you want to get only the first table and drop the first column level:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_html("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Pixar_films")[0]
df = df.droplevel(0, axis=1)

print(df)
```

Prints:

| Film | Release date | Director(s) | Story | Screenplay | Producer(s) | Composer(s) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Toy Story | November 22, 1995 | John Lasseter | Pete Docter, Lasseter, Joe Ranft & Andrew Stanton | Joel Cohen, Alec Sokolow, Stanton & Joss Whedon | Bonnie Arnold & Ralph Guggenheim | Randy Newman |
| A Bug's Life | November 20, 1998 | John LasseterCo-directed by: Andrew Stanton | Lasseter, Joe Ranft & Stanton | Donald McEnery, Bob Shaw & Stanton | Darla K. Anderson & Kevin Reher | Randy Newman |
| Toy Story 2 | November 24, 1999 | John LasseterCo-directed by: Ash Brannon & Lee Unkrich | Brannon, Pete Docter, Lasseter & Andrew Stanton | Doug Chamberlin, Rita Hsiao, Stanton & Chris Webb | Karen Robert Jackson & Helene Plotkin | Randy Newman |
| Monsters, Inc. | November 2, 2001 | Pete DocterCo-directed by: David Silverman & Lee Unkrich | Jill Culton, Docter, Ralph Eggleston & Jeff Pidgeon | Dan Gerson & Andrew Stanton | Darla K. Anderson | Randy Newman |
| Finding Nemo | May 30, 2003 | Andrew StantonCo-directed by: Lee Unkrich | Stanton | Bob Peterson, David Reynolds & Stanton | Graham Walters | Thomas Newman |
| The Incredibles | November 5, 2004 | Brad Bird | Brad Bird | Brad Bird | John Walker | Michael Giacchino |
| Cars | June 9, 2006 | John LasseterCo-directed by: Joe Ranft | Lasseter, Jorgen Klubien & Ranft | Dan Fogelman, Klubien, Lasseter, Phil Lorin, Kiel Murray & Ranft | Darla K. Anderson | Randy Newman |

...and so on.

Comment: YES! Thank you so much. This is exactly how I was picturing the expected output. I appreciate the help.